# Getting undefined at the end of the sentence when printing to console

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
const words = ['hello', 'thank you', 'brother', 'welcome', 'dancing', 'milk', 'bike', 'ruffles'];

const getSentence = (words, index = 0) => {

  if (words[index] === undefined) {
    return;
  }
  return words[index] + ' ' + getSentence(words, index + 1)
}

console.log(getSentence(words));
```

Comment: if you're doing this in the console, that last `undefined` is the return value of the function `console.log` - which is what console.log always returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in last call your function return nothing so it print undefined you should have try to return some like some empty string try this code instead not sure if this will do what you want but give it a try

```
const words = ['hello', 'thank you', 'brother', 'welcome', 'dancing', 'milk', 'bike', 'ruffles'];

const getSentence = (words, index = 0) => {

if (words[index] === undefined) {
    return '';
}
return words[index] + ' ' + getSentence(words, index + 1)
}

console.log(getSentence(words));
```